# SQL получить id товара, по нескольким атрибутам

Tags: php, sql, opencart

Я хочу получить id товара по 2 атрибутам, но mysql выводит 0 строк. 
Пример в бд

```
product_id 44 attribute_id 12 text 3 модуля
product_id 44 attribute_id 13 text Зеленый
```

Делаю такой запрос

```
AND (
        (
        pa.attribute_id = '13' 
        AND pa.text = '1000x800 мм'
    ) 
    AND (
        pa.attribute_id = '14' 
        AND pa.text = 'Зеленый'
    )
)
```

Выводится 0 полей, если же вводить только

```
 (
    pa.attribute_id = '13' 
    AND pa.text = '1000x800 мм'
)
```

Выводятся нужные id. Как сделать правильный запрос?

Вот так выглядит целый запрос

```
    SELECT 
    p.product_id, 
    (
        SELECT 
            AVG(rating) AS total 
        FROM 
            oc_review r1 
        WHERE 
            r1.product_id = p.product_id 
            AND r1.status = '1' 
        GROUP BY 
            r1.product_id
    ) AS rating, 
    (
        SELECT 
            price 
        FROM 
            oc_product_discount pd2 
        WHERE 
            pd2.product_id = p.product_id 
            AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1' 
            AND pd2.quantity = '1' 
            AND (
                (
                    pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' 
                    OR pd2.date_start < NOW()
                ) 
                AND (
                    pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' 
                    OR pd2.date_end > NOW()
                )
            ) 
        ORDER BY 
            pd2.priority ASC, 
            pd2.price ASC 
        LIMIT 
            1
    ) AS discount, 
    (
        SELECT 
            price 
        FROM 
            oc_product_special ps 
        WHERE 
            ps.product_id = p.product_id 
            AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' 
            AND (
                (
                    ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' 
                    OR ps.date_start < NOW()
                ) 
                AND (
                    ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' 
                    OR ps.date_end > NOW()
                )
            ) 
        ORDER BY 
            ps.priority ASC, 
            ps.price ASC 
        LIMIT 
            1
    ) AS special 
FROM 
    oc_product_to_category p2c 
    LEFT JOIN oc_product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) 
    LEFT JOIN oc_product_attribute pa ON (pa.product_id = p.product_id) 
    LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
    LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
WHERE 
    pd.language_id = '1' 
    AND p.status = '1' 
    AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
    AND p2s.store_id = '0' 
    AND p2c.category_id = '46' 
    AND (
        (
            pa.attribute_id = '12' 
            AND pa.text = '5 модулей'
        ) 
        OR (
            pa.attribute_id = '13' 
            AND pa.text = '1000x800 мм'
        ) 
        OR (
            pa.attribute_id = '14' 
            AND pa.text = 'Зеленый'
        )
    ) 
GROUP BY 
    p.product_id 
ORDER BY 
    p.sort_order ASC, 
    LCASE(pd.name) ASC 
LIMIT 
    0, 9
```

Comment: покажите весь запрос. может объединение где не верное.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT product_id
FROM pa
WHERE (attribute_id, text) IN (('13','1000x800 мм'),('14','Зеленый'))
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(product_id) = 2
```

Comment: А что делать в случае если поступают параметры  пустые ?
WHERE (attribute_id, text) IN (('13',''),('14','Зеленый'))

Comment: @kosh ПОЧЕМУ они поступают пустые? Что должно происходить, если значение не указано - выбирать любое, лишь бы было, или именно что искать пустое? А ещё - о таких вещах следовало подумать заранее и описАть все возможные варианты в самОм вопросе.

Comment: Честно, я не подумал об этом. Суть в том что либо пользователь выбирает по одному фильтру, либо сразу всё. И я не могу понять, как сделать этот запрос правильно, а так же написать php скрипт к нему

Comment: Стандартный подход обычно такой: `WHERE (value = @value OR @value = '')`. Правда, он конфликтует с `WHERE .. IN (..)` - проверку придётся трансформировать в блоки сравнения по значениям отдельных полей... хотя намного разумнее такие пары ключ-значение вырезАть ещё на клиенте при формировании запроса (всё одно количество пар для HAVING надо посчитать и вставить в тело либо параметр).

Comment: Спасибо, проблему решил, нужно было всего лишь добавить HAVING COUNT, в моём запросе, и он сработал

Answer (score 0):

```
select product_id from pa where (attribute_id = 13 and text = '1000x800 мм') or (attribute_id = 14 and text = 'Зеленый');
```

**UPD:**

```
select distinct product_id from pa where attribute_id = 13 and text = '1000x800 мм' 
and exists (
select * from pa p 
where p.product_id = pa.product_id and p.attribute_id = 14 and p.text = 'Зеленый');
```

Как один из возможных вариантов.

Comment: Тогда он выводит id товара, в котором есть хотя бы 1 параметр этот, но мне надо чтобы выводился товар только по этим двум атрибутам одновременно (я делаю модуль фильтра на сайт)

Comment: @kosh, понял, щас попробую.

Comment: Спасибо, буду отталкиваться от этого

Comment: В общем, такой вариант не прокатил, если не будет первого параметра (13), то он ничего не выведет, всё равно спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятна структура таблицы и смысл задания фильтрации запроса по ID и текстовому описанию этого ID, если они соответствуют.
Пример написал на sqlite диалекте, думаю не составит труда подправить под mysql, но наверное требуемый запрос будет таким:

```
drop table if exists tab1;

create table 
       tab1       
(
       product_id int,       
       attribute_id int,       
       text text       
);

insert into tab1 select 44, 12, 'зеленый';
insert into tab1 select 44, 13, '1000x800 мм';
insert into tab1 select 45, 12, 'зеленый';
insert into tab1 select 46, 13, '1000x800 мм';

select product_id from tab1 tb1
where 
      exists (select * from tab1 tb2 where tb1.[product_id] = tb2.product_id and tb2.[attribute_id] = 12 AND tb2.text = 'зеленый' ) AND       
      exists (select * from tab1 tb3 where tb1.[product_id] = tb3.product_id and tb3.[attribute_id] = 13 and tb3.text = '1000x800 мм' ) 
group by product_id
```

В результате на выходе получаем только товар с ID - 44:

```
RecNo product_id 
----- ---------- 
    1         44
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую